# What is the difference between routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes() and context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have mvc application with additional area named `account`

I am using `MvcSiteMapProvider` for making breadcrumbs

I have an action which returns details about specific invoice. This action's url is something like `localhost/account/profile/invs-histr/details/ID`, where ID is the id of invoice to display.

I have `accountAreaRegistration.cs` for registering areas routes and I have `RouteConfig.cs` for registering global routes.

Currently, I have to register route for `localhost/account/profile/invs-histr/details/ID` in both files. If I do not register this route in `accountAreaRegistration.cs`, I've got `404 exception`. If I do not register this route in `RouteConfig.cs`, breadcrumbs are not being rendered.

The begining of `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

And `accountAreaRegistration.cs`:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
   context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Can anyone explain me, what is the difference between `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` and `context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`?

Why I should register the route in both files?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it is same thing what i am seeing, you are referring to samething in one case it is via context and in one via routes but ultimate result is same

Comment: But still it acts in a different way - if route is not placed in RouteConfig - no breadcrumbs are being rendered. If route is not registered within accountAreaRegistration - I receive 404 error while trying to access account/profile/invs-histr/details action

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an extension method, so that the object from which you call it is the first parameter. This parameter is a `RouteCollection`, and this collection is different in both cases:

- In the first call are registered the routes of controllers "in the root" of the application which have routing attributes
- In the second call the same is being done for controllers inside the current area

If you want to avoid the second call for each area, you can decorate your controllers with the `[RouteArea("AreaName")]` attribute.

If you want to have a better understanding of attribute routing, see this doc: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) Pay special attention to the Areas section.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this article you've provided here really helped me!

Comment: The link is dead now :/